# aws localstack connect aws resource directly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I have below lambda code,

```
import boto3
import json
import time

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('my-header')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  body = json.loads(event["body"])
  table.put_item(Item=body)
```

Which works fine with AWS.

Now I wanted to add some test that runs on localstack.
When I deployed the same code, localstack lambda is contacting AWS Dynamodb instead of localstack dynamoDB and gets failed with a Token exception.

When I add an endpoint like below it works,

```
if os.environ.get("LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME"):
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',endpoint_url='http://' + os.environ["LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME"] + ':4566')
else:
  dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
```

Is it possible to connect localstack dynamodb without using endpoint_url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no global, profile, or environment variable configuration that would allow this. There is an ongoing effort to finalize a [proposal for this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/pull/230) that would allow you to set `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL` or `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL_<service>` to control this behavior.

Until then, the `endpoint_url` parameter must be explicitly requested for each service.

Additional references:

- https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1375
- https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1270